# Null Result in mysqli_fetch_all on live server

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp, localhost, hosting

I have reviewed many stackoverflow que for this query and found it requires mysqlnd extension but got PHP 5.4+ has mysqlnd as default.
also I have

XAMPP php version : 5.6.3

Wamp php version : 5.5.12

live php version : 5.5.27

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456","new_project") or die("Database not connected. Please contact ADMINISTRATOR");

$result = $link->query("select * from user_master");

$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

return $row;
```

Getting $row with all data in  $row on localhost but getting NULL on live server.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have any rows in the database of the live server?

Comment: yes obviously  phplover it has more than 20 records.

Comment: if you can show the table structure.

Comment: yes sure its simple just 3 fields
user_id int(11) AUTO INC  | user_name varchar (500) | user_password varchar (5000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');

if ($mysqlnd) {
echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';  

 } else {

echo 'not enabled';
}
```

Yes 5.4+ provide mysqlnd but check once its active or not?!
mysqli_fetch_all : will give you all the records in array at a time

please try with mysqli_fetch_array and use loop like this.

```
$myArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$myArray[] = $row;
}
```

YOU GET WILL ALL THE RECORDS IN $myArray.

Comment: but still anyone has clue with **mysqli_fetch_all**